# How to remap Menu key to Super?

Tags: keyboard, menu, remapping

I'm running Ubuntu MATE 20.04 on an old Toshiba Satellite that has a menu key instead of a second Windows/Super key, and I'd like to remap it so that it functions as Super.

So far, I've tried `xev | grep keycode`, which tells me that the menu key is keycode `135`. When I write

`keycode 135 = Super_R`

to `.Xmodmap` and reboot, the key doesn't work, and no longer returns a keycode to `xev`.

What am I doing wrong?